# PHP MYSQL Simple Program Logic

Tags: php, mysql, logic

I have list of say 100 Products Listed in My Website.Every product has its own page in website.Now when ever i want some discount or any other offer say for 5 products I will write an if condition in products.php which display the product. products.php page displays different products by taking different productId in its url as below.So for Different productId different products are displayed

e.g
http://www.samplesite.com/products?ProductId=15

What I want is since i am changing the Discounts and Offers for products in Regular basis what would be the best way to store the product id other than database like storing in a constant which is available to all pages in the site

Answer (score 1):

1. each product must have a uniques ID, integer value
2. each product might have a discount attached, discount linked to the product using the product unique id
3. the uniques product id must be available for all pages involved, like if the curent page displayed is the category page where the product belongs to, the product will be listed there and the id should be available
4. if you are using only php, put the id in the link
5. if using javascript, put id in the id tag and play with it